# Is $ A = \{ (x_n) : \sum_{n = 1}^\infty x_n \leq r \} \subset \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} $ compact?

Tags: general-topology

Let be $r > 0, $ is the space $ A = \{ (x_n) \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}  : \sum_{n = 1}^\infty  x_n \leq r \} $ in the space $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ compact ?

The open sets of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ are the $ U = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} U_i$, where $ U_i \neq \mathbb{N}$ for a finite numbers of $i$'s. Given a cover $(U_\alpha)$ of $A$, I have tried to get a finite subcover without sucess. I don't know if it's the best way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the open set definition say $U_i \neq 0$ for a finite number of $i$'s?

Comment: $A\subseteq [0,r]^\mathbb{N}$ which is compact by Tychonoff's theorem. So, it is enough to show $A$ is closed.

Comment: Please review your definition of $A$.

Comment: @PhoemueX, I have edited now. Thanks.

Comment: There are too many $n$'s in the definition of $A$.

Comment: Review the definition of $A$ again.

Comment: I have edited again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=\lfloor r\rfloor$; then $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in A$ if and only if $\sum_{n\ge 0}x_n\le m$, since the terms of $x$ are non-negative integers. Moreover, it’s clear that if $x\in A$, then $x_n\le m$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $A\subseteq\{0,1,\ldots,m\}^{\Bbb N}$. The space $\{0,1,\ldots,m\}^{\Bbb N}$, being a product of compact Hausdorff spaces, is a compact Hausdorff space, so $A$ will be compact if and only if it is a closed subset of $\{0,1,\ldots,m\}^{\Bbb N}$. In fact $A$ is closed in $\{0,1,\ldots,m\}^{\Bbb N}$, and I’ll point you towards a proof.

Suppose that $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\{0,1,\ldots,m\}^{\Bbb N}\setminus A$; then $\sum_{n\ge 0}x_n>m$.

- Show that there is a set $F\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that $|F|=m+1$, and $x_n\ge 1$ for each $n\in F$.
- Then let $$U_n=\begin{cases}\{x_n\},&\text{if }n\in F\\\{0,1,\ldots,m\},&\text{if }n\in\Bbb N\setminus F\;,\end{cases}$$ and show that $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$ is an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $A$.
- Conclude that $\Bbb N\rangle\in\{0,1,\ldots,m\}^{\Bbb N}\setminus A$ is open and hence that $A$ is closed in $\Bbb N\rangle\in\{0,1,\ldots,m\}^{\Bbb N}$ and therefore compact.

**Added:** **bof**’s comment below made me think about the possibility of avoiding the Tikhonov theorem and proving directly that $A$ is sequentially compact. (Since $A$ is metrizable, this is equivalent to proving compactness of $A$.) This turns out to be entirely possible.

Let $m$ be as above, and let $\sigma=\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence in $A$, where $x^{(n)}=\langle x_k^{(n)}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$; I’ll show that $\sigma$ has a subsequence converging to an element of $A$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let

$$F_n=\left\{k\in\Bbb N:x_k^{(n)}>0\right\}\;.$$

If there is an infinite $M\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that $\{F_n:n\in M\}$ is pairwise disjoint, then $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in M\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\sigma$ converging to the zero sequence in $A$. Otherwise, let $k_0$ be the smallest natural number belonging to infinitely many of the sets $F_n$. Since $x_k^{(n)}\le m$ for all $k,n\in\Bbb N$, there is an $\ell_0\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that

$$M_0=\left\{n\in\Bbb N:k_0\in F_n\text{ and }x_{k_0}^{(n)}=\ell_0\right\}$$

is infinite. Suppose that there is an infinite $M\subseteq M_0$ such that $\{F_n\setminus\{k_0\}:n\in M\}$ is pairwise disjoint; then $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in M\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\sigma$ converging in $A$ to $y=\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$, where

$$y_k=\begin{cases}
\ell_0,&\text{if }k=k_0\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

If there is no such $M$, we can argue as before to get $k_1\in\Bbb N\setminus\{k_0\}$ and $\ell_1\in\Bbb Z^+$, such that

$$M_1=\left\{n\in M_0:k_1\in F_n\text{ and }x_{k_1}^{(n)}=\ell_1\right\}$$

is infinite. If there is an infinite $M\subseteq M_1$ such that $\{F_n\setminus\{k_0,k_1\}:n\in M\}$ is pairwise disjoint, $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in M\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\sigma$ converging in $A$ to $y=\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$, where

$$y_k=\begin{cases}
\ell_0,&\text{if }k=k_0\\
\ell_1,&\text{if }k=k_1\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

If there is no such $M$, we can repeat the reduction to get $k_2\in\Bbb N\setminus\{k_0,k_1\}$,$\ell_2\in\Bbb Z^+$, and an infinite

$$M_2=\left\{n\in M_1:k_2\in F_n\text{ and }x_{k_2}^{(n)}=\ell_2\right\}\;.$$

Suppose that in this fashion we’ve reached an infinite $M_r$ and have $\ell_0,\ldots,\ell_r\in\Bbb Z^+$ and distinct $k_0,\ldots,k_r\in\Bbb N$ such that $\{k_0,\ldots,k_r\}\subseteq F_n$ and $x_{k_j}^{(n)}=\ell_j$ for each $n\in M_r$ and $j=0,\ldots,r$. Clearly

$$\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}x_k^{(n)}\ge\sum_{j=0}^r\ell_j\ge r+1\;,$$

so $r<m$. In other words, the reduction process must stop at some $r<m$.

This means that there is an infinite $M\subseteq M_r$ such that $\{F_n\setminus\{k_0,\ldots,k_r\}:n\in M\}$ is pairwise disjoint, and $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in M\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\sigma$ converging in $A$ to $y=\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$, where

$$y_k=\begin{cases}
\ell_j,&\text{if }k=k_j\text{ for some }j\in\{0,\ldots,r\}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Note that it’s possible that this is a constant subsequence, i.e., that $x^{(n)}=y$ for all $n\in M$.

Comment: I wonder if this can be done more directly (without using Tychonoff), i.e., by proving directly that an infinite sequence in $A$ has a subsequence converging to a point in $A.$ Some sort of induction on $m$ I guess.

Comment: @bof: It is possible, and without induction on $m$; I’ve added the argument to my answer.